# Stay on the same textbox control inside a listbox whilst using keyboard navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox, wpf-controls

I'm very new to WPF so go easy

I have a bound list box which is bounce to a datasource.

I have created a data template for the items in the list box and some of the columns of data need to be editable.  to make them editable I have created a bound textbox in a data template in a resource file.

My question is. Once I am in the textbox and have edited the data.  How do I then use the keyboard to arrow down to the next line and have it automatically give focus to the same textbox on the next line down.

I have been searching for 2 days now but no solution seems to fit my problem

Template in resource file;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" x:Name="dTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_StockCode}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvTemplate}" Width="80"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_PartNo}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvTemplate}" Width="70"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_desc}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvTemplate}" Width="245"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="liProfileStockQty" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=b2b_ProfileStockQty}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvTextBoxTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_StockQty}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_DBCost}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_InternetCost}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_PerCost}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_TotalCost}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>            
        <Separator Width="2"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_TradePrice}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=b2b_PerTrade}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvLabelRightAlignTemplate}" Width="50"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="liDiscountTrade" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=b2b_DiscountTrade}" Control.Template="{StaticResource lvTextBoxTemplate}" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

my Main Xaml looks like this...

```
<Window x:Class="B2BPricing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:B2BPricing" 
    Title="B2B Pricing"  Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="/B2BPricing;component/NewCEF.ico" >
<Window.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ListViewResources.xaml" />                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <my:B2BPricingDataSet x:Key="b2bPricing" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="b2bPricingViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=B2bPricing, Source={StaticResource b2bPricing}}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="b2bPricingsupplierViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=B2bPricing_supplier, Source={StaticResource b2bPricingViewSource}}" />            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource b2bPricingViewSource}" Name="MainGrid" >
    <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="836,12,0,0" Name="resultLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Stock Code" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,34,0,0" Name="lblStockCode" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Part No." Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,34,864,0" Name="lblPartNo" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Description" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,34,776,0" Name="lblDescription" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,609,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Stock Code" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="b2b_StockCodeTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=b2b_StockCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,644,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Description" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="b2b_descTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=b2b_desc, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="386" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,609,0,0" Name="grdSupplier" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Supplier" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,4,0,6" Name="tbSupplier" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Text="159" />
    </Grid>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" Height="542" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             Margin="0,60,0,0" Name="lbPricing" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="983" IsManipulationEnabled="True" 
             SelectionMode="Extended" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
             KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
             KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Once">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="4" Background="{StaticResource myGroupingBrush}" Foreground="White">
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Content="_Load" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,694,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="230,311,246,385" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="526" Visibility="Visible" IsIndeterminate="False" />        

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource b2bPricingsupplierViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,-3,0,0" Name="grid4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Supplier: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=sup_fullname}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Name="sup_fullnameLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center" />            
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="_Show" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,694,0,0" Name="btnTextBoxContents" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnTextBoxContents_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and the c#:

```
 private void btnTextBoxContents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = (lbPricing.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)lbPricing.ItemsPanel.FindName("liProfileStockQty", lbPricing);
        //TextBox tb = dTemplate.FindName("liProfileStockQty") as TextBox;
        resultLabel.Content = tb.Text;
    }
```

This is not the only way I've tried.  I also tried copying something like this.

```
foreach (LinePosition item in this.ListLinePositions.Items)
                {
                      CheckBox cb = FindByName("checkedPosition",
                                                (ListViewItem)this.ListLinePositions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)) as CheckBox;    
                }
```

but replacing that examples checkbox with the textbox control i'm tring to find